Kotlin serializer fails on Enum if changed
Weirdest issue happening for a few days now.
I have a data class that we serialize/deserialize regularly. Been using it and adding things to it for years now basically.
I'm at a point now where things run fine but I can't touch this class, as the serializer will just throw if I add/remove a field, complaining that one of the Enum classes can't be decoded.

JsonElement decoding of class X went wrong: DisplayMode does not contain element with name 'daily'

internal enum class DisplayMode {
    @SerialName("daily")
    DAILY,

    @SerialName("monthly")
    MONTHLY,
}

If I remove this field, another Enum fails. If I remove all enums from this data class, it goes through fine.
How did it got in this stuck state, where it's fine as long I don't touch it?
